# Postgres Return NULL Table

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a Postgres function which returns a table "RETURNS TABLE......"

There is some business rules in place in the code.  If certain conditions are not met, I want to return just an empty record set.   Is there a simple way to do this?  Or do I need to select a NULL for each column returned?

Right now if I try to return just NULL, it complains:  ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type.

Comment: Without seeing the code it is hard to say. If you are selecting from another table could you just do a `SELECT` that you know does not return anything?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please ensure you include the [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can ensure we assist you as best as we can.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using PL/pgSQL, you can use a plain `RETURN;` statement without an argument to return an empty result set.

Comment: Thanks!   Looks like a RETURN statement by itself will ignore the actual RECORD layout, and just give an empty set.    Much appreciated!!!

Comment: That ignores nothing. In set returning functions, you return a row with `RETURN NEXT;` and end the result set with `RETURN;`.